# How to use raw video buffer for steaming in Vue js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, web-scraping, video

I am using this [package](https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper) in node js to scrape the data from TikTok and store all the details in MongoDB. The below code gives the raw code of the video

**Code**

```
'use strict';
 const TikTokScraper = require('tiktok-scraper');
 const got = require('got');
 const fs = require('fs');

 var main = async (user, numOfVideos) => {

 try {
 const posts = await TikTokScraper.user(user, { number: numOfVideos
 });

 //THIS BELOW CODE WILL BE USED IN VUE JS TO FETCH THE VIDEO BUFFER
 //FOR EXPLANATION I ADDED THIS CODE

 const headers = {

  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) 
   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.80 Safari/537.36',
   Referer: 'https://www.tiktok.com/',
   Cookie: 'tt_webid_v2=689854141086886123'
 };
    
   

  const videoMeta = await 
  TikTokScraper.getVideoMeta(posts.collector[0].webVideoUrl, { headers });


  console.log(JSON.stringify(videoMeta, null, 2));
  const url = videoMeta.collector[0].videoUrl;

  await got.stream(url, { headers: videoMeta.headers 
  }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.html'));   //==============RAW video store in file

  // got.stream(url, { headers: videoMeta.headers 
  }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.mp4'));

  } catch (error) {

  return error;
    }
  };

  main('zachking', 1);
```

If I used the out.html file in the vide tag then the video will be played

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>

<source src="./out.html" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

**Want**

I will create a project in **VUE JS** where TikTok videos will be played when a user clicks on any video then get the buffer, and play the video in Vue js. I could not understand how to use this code in vue js, because the below code gives the video buffer OR whats another alternate way to get TikTok videos in node js and used TikTok videos mp4 links in the video tag

```
const headers = {

  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) 
   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.80 Safari/537.36',
   Referer: 'https://www.tiktok.com/',
   Cookie: 'tt_webid_v2=689854141086886123'
 };

  const videoMeta = await 
  TikTokScraper.getVideoMeta(webVideoUrl, { headers });


  console.log(JSON.stringify(videoMeta, null, 2));
  const url = videoMeta.collector[0].videoUrl;

  await got.stream(url, { headers: videoMeta.headers 
  }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.html'));   //==============BUFFER store in file

  // got.stream(url, { headers: videoMeta.headers 
  }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.mp4'));
```

Comment: **(1)** This buffer is it an array? Are you asking how to use array (of video bytes) as input for a video tag? If yes then look at `createObjectURL`  **(2)** If you know the video url, and are reading its bytes into a buffer, why not use the same url in the video tag?

Comment: 1- It's not array, it's a simple buffer or RAW video. Buffer need some URL and headers see the getVideoMeta function in this code.

Comment: **(1)** What is `videoMeta.collector[0].videoUrl;`? Is it not the MP4 url that can be used as `.src` for a video tag? **(2)** Looks like you might have to write or store buffer values into an array (instead of writing to file, because array can be fed into a video tag) **(3)** I don't use Tik-Tok so if you have a link to some short video page, I can check it for clues about the related MP4 url.

Comment: (1) It's not the mp4 link. Send request on this URL (videoMeta.collector[0].videoUrl) and add headers to get the RAW video. If you use my above code then you get more information about this RAW video. See the [example](https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper#download-video)